# ¿Como hago un ciclo con arreglo que se detenga hasta que todos sus elementos sean 0?

Tags: java, array, bucle-for, bucles, algoritmos

Tengo que hacer un algoritmo Round Robin para un programa, y estoy tratando de hacer por mi cuenta el algoritmo, pero no encuentro la manera en que se repita el ciclo for hasta que haya tomado en cuenta todos los números del arreglo. Pensé hacerlo como está mi código, en irle restando la cantidad del quantum al arreglo para que se volvieran ceros y que el ciclo for se detuviera hasta que todos los elementos del arreglo fueran cero, pero no me funciona la sentencia y se detiene. Abajo les dejó mi código. Le agradezco a quien se tome el tiempo de ayudarme.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
 
public class algoPruebaRR{
    public static void main(String arg[]){
        String respuesta, nomProceso;
 
        int numProcesos, opcion, cRafaga, rafaga, rafagaUno, quantum;
        String nombreProceso[];
        int rafagas[];
        int prioridad[];
        int llegada[];
        int menorAMayorRafaga[];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 
        do{
            System.out.println("PROGRAMA PARA SIMULAR ALGORITMOS DE PROCESOS");
            System.out.println("¿Cuantos procesos son?");
            numProcesos = sc.nextInt();
 
            nombreProceso = new String[numProcesos];
            rafagas = new int[numProcesos];
            llegada = new int[numProcesos];
            prioridad = new int[numProcesos];
            menorAMayorRafaga = new int[numProcesos];
 
            for(int i = 0; i < numProcesos; i++){
                System.out.println("Ingresa el nombre del proceso, de acuerdo a su orden de llegada");
                nombreProceso[i] = sc.next();
                System.out.println("Ingresa su ráfaga de CPU");
                rafagas[i]=sc.nextInt();
                //menorAMayorRafaga[i] = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Ingresa su tiempo de llegada");
                llegada[i] = sc.nextInt();
            }
 
            System.out.println("MENÚ DE PROCESOS");
            System.out.println("1. FIFO");
            System.out.println("2. SJF");
            System.out.println("3. Round Robin");
            System.out.println("4. Queves multi-nivel");
            System.out.println("5. Multi-nivel feedback");
            opcion = sc.nextInt();
 
            if (opcion == 3){
                System.out.println("Ingresa el quantum");
                quantum = sc.nextInt();
                cRafaga = 0;
 
 
                    for(int i = 0; i<rafagas.length; i++){
                        do{
                            rafaga = rafagas[i];
                            nomProceso = nombreProceso[i];
 
 
                            if (rafaga >= quantum){
                                System.out.print("PROCESO: " + nomProceso);
                                System.out.print(cRafaga);
                                cRafaga = cRafaga + quantum;
                                System.out.print("-" + cRafaga);
                                System.out.println();
                                rafagas[i]=rafagas[i]-quantum;
                            }
 
                            if(rafaga < quantum){
                                System.out.print("PROCESO: " + nomProceso);
                                System.out.print(cRafaga);
                                cRafaga = cRafaga + rafaga;
                                System.out.print("-" + cRafaga);
                                System.out.println();
                                rafagas[i]=rafagas[i]-rafaga;
                            }
                        }while(rafagas.length==0);
 
 
 
 
                    }
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rafagas));
 
 
 
 
            }
 
 
 
        System.out.println("Quieres hacer otra operaci�n (Si/No)?: ");
            respuesta = sc.next();
            respuesta = respuesta.toLowerCase();
        }while(respuesta.equals("si"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! si rafaga es un int... nunca su length va a ser cero, porque el numero cero, como string, mide 1 ;)... cambia rafagas.length==0 por rafagas==0 y listo....

Comment: @gbianchi intenté lo que me dijiste, pero no funcionó. Me envió el siguiente error:  error: bad operand types for binary operator '=='
                        }while(rafagas==0);
                                      ^    
  first type:  int[]
  second type: int

Comment: perdon... era rafaga lo que estas buscando... si no, vos cuando queres cortar el ciclo?

Comment: @gbianchi le intenté con ráfaga!=0 y si me corrió el arreglo hasta que quedó en ceros. La cuestión es que no me da el resultado correcto. Me queda así: Ingresa el quantum
10
PROCESO: corel0-10
PROCESO: corel10-20
PROCESO: corel20-29
PROCESO: calculadora29-39
PROCESO: powerpoint39-48
PROCESO: excel48-58
PROCESO: excel58-59
PROCESO: chrome59-65
PROCESO: word65-73
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] Al ser un Round robin debería quedar así: corel 0-10, calculadora 10-20, powerpoint 20-29, excel 29-39, chrome 39-45, word 45-53, corel 53-63, excel 63-64 y corel 64-73. Creo que hice mal el ciclo.

Comment: ya lo que me decis no tiene sentido porque no se cual es el resultado correcto, al no saber que hace el proceso y que queres que haga....

Comment: Por favor lee [example] para que sea claro que es lo que esperas que haga tu algoritmo